# Get request to Couchbase Database failing?

Tags: scala, akka, couchbase

I have a scala project that is connected to a couchbase database.  I am making a get request to retrieve a document from the couchbase database.  My method looks like this:

```
 def findAll(): Future[String] = {
   CouchDriver.plannerBucket.get[JsValue]("1").map(result => (result.get \ "area").as[String])
  }
```

I'm invoking it all this in a http-akka router:

```
   complete(
  couchbaseRepository.findAll().map(v => {
  HttpResponse(200, entity = 
  HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, v))
     })
   )
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error during processing of request: 'java.lang.NullPointerException (No error message supplied)'. Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response. To change default exception handling behavior, provide a custom ExceptionHandler.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

The odd thing is, when I change the method to this:

```
CouchDriver.plannerBucket.underlyingBucket.get("1")
```

And evaluate the expression in Intellij, it gets the document. 
Not sure what the issue is!

Comment: If `plannerBucket` is just a Couchbase SDK Bucket reference, you can't just cast it into `JsValue` since it is returning a Document. Can you try without the JsValue cast and see if it works?

Comment: Hi there, I get the same NullPointerException when I remove the JsValue cast!  Thanks

Comment: What's in result, inside the map()?

Comment: The map method never gets invoked - I get the message 'Cannot resolve symbol map'

Comment: I see. Have you tried bumping up the Couchbase logging and seeing if there are any issues reported from the server?